# The less-known features

Tags: discussion

Jukka has [mentioned](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/about-retagging-as-tag-removed) a [feature](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search) (a page for more advanced searching) that I was not aware of. Are there other less-known features that you have found useful?

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange has an experimental feature called timeline view ([example](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/597/timeline)).  It is useful when you want to know when a post was made, an answer was accepted, and so on (but be careful because it does not always show the complete history).  See [my answer](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/useful-userscripts/508#508) to another question for more details and a link to a user script which makes the timeline view easier to use.

Comment: I've found timeline view really useful to summarise recent activity.  This saves a lot of time when there are many long comment threads and answers for a question.

Answer (score 7):

We have chat ! Specifically, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47/theoretical-computer-science takes you to a chat area for cstheory.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a less-known feature but a less-known practice.  I hope that this belongs here anyway.

[Changes of features and policies on Stack Overflow are listed in a thread on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow).  Note that not everything on the list applies to cstheory.stackexchange.com or meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com.  A Stack Exchange addict (**unlike me**) who is using a feed reader might want to subscribe to the feed for that thread to become a better Stack Exchange addict (**unlike me**).

Comment: This answer proves that you are a SO addict, actually a better one. ;)

Comment: @Kaveh: I clarified the answer a little in response to your comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

[Markup for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482).  They automatically link to the list of tagged questions.  This is sometimes useful on Meta and in tag wikis.  Examples:

- `[tag:graph-theory]` → [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) (points to a tag on parent)
- `[meta-tag:scope]` → [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) (points to a tag on Meta; only available on Meta)
- `[tag:this-tag-does-not-exist]` → [this-tag-does-not-exist](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-tag-does-not-exist) (also works for a nonexistent tag)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in comments: [tag:graph-theory]

Comment: @Jukka: Too bad. :(

Answer (score 5):

Hover the mouse on the following quote and

> you will see a spoiler text.

See [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text/71396#71396) for more information.  Not that I think that this is useful on cstheory.stackexchange.com.  :)

Comment: This is a cool feature!

Comment: neat feature. might be useful if people start posting puzzle solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Meta Stack Overflow has a similar thread: [Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) by JosephStyons.  In particular, I like the following:

- [View the source of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/8219#8219)
- [Tooltip on hover on a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/17622#17622)
- [Calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/69632#69632)

Answer (score 4):

In the right sidebar, the date below "Latest Activity" is a link that takes you directly to the latest addition/change.

Comment: good finding! I have been hoping for this feature for a long time...

Comment: To supplement this answer, clicking the last-modified date/time of each question in a list of questions has the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

[The review page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/review).

Shows answers by new users. There is also a button under answers with negative or zero votes named "flag for removal".

Comment: Also contains an optional custom filter *Containing: "thank"* 
and custom sorts: 1. Shortest first 2. Most commented 3. Reverse Order. I found it on [SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/).

Comment: How dumb of me! I've just found this feature and wanted to report it here. Thanks Kaveh for finding it early :)

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed that there are a few short cuts for linking on the main site (particularly useful when commenting).

1. for Math.SE you can type `[Math.SE]` and it turns into [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com).
2. for FAQ you can simply write `[FAQ]` and it turns into [FAQ](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Wow.  This will be useful.  How did you find it?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, posted a comment with a link to [Math.SE] where I forgot to put the url part. (ps: it seems that the trick also works for commenting on meta).

Answer (score 2):

The site's [privileges page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/).

It show the reputation required for performing various task.

Comment: Yes, this is sometimes useful.  Also note that the number showing your reputation points (in the bar at the top of every page) is a link to it.

Comment: I didn't know that it is a link! :)

Answer (score 2):

[User League](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/) ranks users based on reputation gained during last [year](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/year/cstheory), [quarter](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/quarter/cstheory), [month](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/month/cstheory), [week](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/week/cstheory).

Comment: The page also has a table for the number of users in each reputation range.

Answer (score 2):

[data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used to extract and query various types of information about the sites (posts, users, ...). Some popular queries can be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/queries).

Comment: The [data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputersciencemeta/queries) is out!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently found the [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) to be a useful feature of stackexchange for following several sites.

For example, here is a [filter I use](http://stackexchange.com/filters/26226/artems-interests).